# Where is the orange block that says 'Item (random) of list'? I am lost

Tags: random, mit-scratch

I am taking an online coding course for beginners and we he is creating a randomizer that selects a random color from a list of colors that we created. I am trying to follow along step by step but I CANNOT find the orange block that he is using that says
'item (random) of list'. I found a similar orange block, but it doesn't have the 'random' dropdown option. Am I missing something here?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The dropdwn option there was removed in scratch 3.0 as far as I know, so that's probably the reason you can't find what you're looking for. What you still can do though is generate a random index to use there instead:

[image]

For a list of length n, that will choose a random number from 1 to n and then return the list element at that position, giving you a random element of that list.

Answer (score 0):

This feature still exists. Although peabrainiac's answer was the simplest -  you can also type the work "random" somewhere > copy it to your clipboard > paste it into the item of list. It will work the same. You must copy and paste it as it doesn't not support non-numeric values being entered directly.